# Configure HTML semantics in WebStorm

Tags: html, intellij-idea, webstorm

I want to set different colors for different HTML elements.

`div`, `main`, `header`, `section`: Each individual color. This will make the file much easier to read.

I also want to set a color for my own React components: `Button`, `Card`, `Spinner`.

They are all the same color! This is very difficult to navigate.

This seems like a simple task for the IDE, but for a very long time I can not find this setting. Please advise any solutions. Ready to install any plugin, the main thing is to be able to customize the colors yourself.

Comment: This feature request from YouTrack just looks like the one you are looking for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-330

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request for an IDE.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Think it's impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried several plugins like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12895-comments-highlighter but it doesn't work on HTML/JSX tags, so it's better to vote for the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-330. Feel free to watch the YouTrack item in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.